# Matlab plot functionality

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to do something relatively simple using plots in Matlab, but it is not working. In concept the idea is simple. As a simple example I tried this,

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 2 3 4 5];

TColor1 = 'b';
TLine1 = '-';
plot(x,y,TLine1,TColor1)
```

I want to use predefined strings to change the properties of the plot. The color string works correctly, but the line string doesn't work. I don't understand the problem with the code.

The reason I need this functionality is I have big code where I output large amounts of plots inside several 'for' loops. I need to have the capability to change the plot properties outside the “for” loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
plot(x,y, [TLine1,TColor1])
```

(Note the square brackets.)

Comment: @GradyF.MathewsIv This works because plot expects a single string (character array) as third argument, and with the bracket notation, you create an array out of the elements enclosed.